# What is the application root path of an axis2 .aar file

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have an axis2 archive file(aar) which I would like to deploy to a axis2 web app. Usually in a `.war` archive, we can get access to application root path using `request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")`. I understand there is something for the web service to access files in the server. I tried using [`ConfigurationContext.getRealPath("/")`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/context/ConfigurationContext.html). But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to my case.

https://community.jboss.org/thread/221937

If you use Windows 7, aar seems to regard user account folder as a root.

Comment: Well I did try that once. Like said it pointed to the user account folder. But is that the best practice? I thought all your web application related files(properties, external files, etc.)should be contained within your application path.

Comment: Oh, the reason I did that is that the open-source jar required me to place the resource at the root path of AAR. In other cases, I usually put required resources(text, image and etc. ) into a jar and use getResourceStream to use them.

Answer (score 0):

For your Axis2 to work, you don't need an **aar** file.

**services.xml** file can be in either of the below locations for the Axis2 to work.

1. repository/services/SimpleService/meta-inf/services.xml
2. WEB-INF/services/SimpleService/meta-inf/services.xml

> This will help us in avoiding an extra step of generating the aar file.

**ServiceDeployer.java**

```
 * <p>
 * Standard Axis2 service Deployer which use services.xml file to build
 * services. ServiceDeployer can be used with Axis2 archive (.aar) or exploded
 * directory structure. Some of the example formats given below.
 * </p>
 * <p>Examples : <p>
 *        <ul>
 *          <li>repository/services/SimpleService.aar/meta-inf/services.xml</li>
 *          <li>repository/services/SimpleService/meta-inf/services.xml</li>
 *          <li>WEB-INF/services/SimpleService.aar/meta-inf/services.xml</li>
 *          <li>WEB-INF/services/SimpleService/meta-inf/services.xml</li>
 *       </ul>
 
     InputStream servicexmlStream = serviceClassLoader
            .getResourceAsStream("META-INF/services.xml");
    if (servicexmlStream == null) {
        servicexmlStream = serviceClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("meta-inf/services.xml");
    } else {
        metainf = "META-INF";
    }
```

https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/org/apache/axis2/deployment/ServiceDeployer.html